# Application of Itô formula to stochastic heat equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded set with boundary $\partial \Omega,$ and consider the following stochastic heat equation
$$
\begin{cases}
du(x,t)=(\Delta u(x,t)+f(x,t))dt+\sigma u(x,t)dB(t),\quad (x,t) \in \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+, \\
u(x,0)=u_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad x\in \Omega,\\
u(x,t)=0, \quad (x,t) \in \partial\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+.
\end{cases}
$$
where $B(t)$ is a Brownian motion and $f \in L^2(\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+).$

I'm trying to apply Itô's formula to $\Vert \partial_tu(x,t) \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$ and I'm wondering if it even makes sense, given that I have no prior information about $\partial_tu(x,0)$?

Comment: I don't see why you need particular information about $\partial_{t} u(x,0)$ in order to apply Ito.

Comment: @Tobsn, to apply Itô's formula, the term $\Vert \partial_tu(x,0)\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}$ will appear. Hence, it needs to be finite.